# jquery datepicker, show names of selected days

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I try to insert the names of selected days from datepicker - with no result so far...

My code looks like:

```
$("#date_from, #date_to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1d",
    minDate: "+1d",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    monthNamesShort: ["Sty", "Lut", "Mar", "Kwi", "Maj", "Cze", "Lip", "Sie", "Wrz", "Paz", "Lis", "Gru"],
    dayNamesMin: ["Nie", "Pon", "Wt", "Śr", "Czw", "Pt", "Sob"],
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    constrainInput: true,
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
    firstDay: 1, // Start with Monday
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        if (this.id == 'date_from') {
            var dateMin = $('#date_from').datepicker("getDate");
            var dateMax = $('#date_to').datepicker('getDate');
            var rent_date_from = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + 1);
            var rent_date_to = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + 29);
            $('#date_to').datepicker("option", "minDate", rent_date_from);
            $('#date_to').datepicker("option", "maxDate", rent_date_to);

        }
        $('#day_of_week1').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', dateMin));
        $('#day_of_week2').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', dateMax));
        compute(); //Add compute
    }

});
```

I have two `input` field (`#day_of_week1`, `#day_of_week2`). I get a value but only from the first field (in the `#day_of_week1`), but I can't get the value from the second one. I don't know where is the problem?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: logic seems flawed trying to get date from second date field before it has been selected. Make a demo in jsfillde.net